# Allure reports showing the testng tests that are not run as 'Broken'

Tags: java, testng, reporting, allure

When generating allure reports for TestNG tests, the tests that are not run are shown as 'broken' under xUnit. The default TestNG report shows the correct count of test cases that are run, but allure reports shows all the tests from testng.xml including those that are not run.

Answer (score 1):

Allure marks all tests which has ended with unexpected exception (is not instance of `AssertionError`) as `BROKEN`. It seems that there is an exception some where in cofiguration methods, I suppose. And yeah, Allure show all tests, including configuration methods and disabled tests, you can fix it in your custom adaptor.

Comment: So, using TestNG IAnnotationTransformer listener, i'm setting the annotation enabled=false at runtime based on condition. Allure report is showing all the tests that are marked as enabled=false as BROKEN. Tests are run at all, but still Allure reports showing them as BROKEN. However, the default emailable-report.html generated shows only the tests that are run.

Comment: It's because Allure checks disabled tests during `onStart` event, which is related to suite level. And, as I remember, `IAnnotationTransformer` is invoked before each test method. So, you skip tests, but for Allure they are just tests which have been invoked but not finished succesfully and without exception, and it marks them as `BROKEN`.

Comment: In my case, even thought the test case is passed, it is showing in Broken! What is the reason